# Simple route: No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have 2 simple routes in my WebApiConfig:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "Speaker",
routeTemplate: "api/presentations/{presentationid}/speakers/{id}",
defaults: new { controller = "speakers", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "Presentations",
routeTemplate: "api/presentations/{id}",
defaults: new { controller = "presentations", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

I can't get the first route to work.. I have a SpeakersController with a Get:

```
IEnumerable<SpeakerModel> Get(int presentationid)
{
return _speakerService.GetSpeakersByPresentationId(presentationid).Select(s => _modelFactory.Create(s));
}
```

And when I call : http://localhost/Api/Presentations/1/Speakers via a get request I get this error :

"Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost/Api/Presentations/1/Speakers'.",
"MessageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'Speakers' that matches the request."

Answer (score 0):

I did not have a  public access modifier on my method.

```
**public** IEnumerable<SpeakerModel> Get(int presentationid)
{
return _speakerService.GetSpeakersByPresentationId(presentationid).Select(s =>     _modelFactory.Create(s));
}
```